# storing a key in unmaned devices in a secure way

Tags: encryption, communication, secret-key, storing-data, symmetric-key

Do you have any solution for storing a key (for encryption and decryption for communication) in unmanned devices , where a hacker can access the devices completely and there is no possibility for protect the device? I mean software solution for storing a key.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion: Encrypt the key, using an RSA public key.  Store the RSA encrypted key on the device, and let anybody access it.  Only people with the RSA private key will be able to decrypt and see the actual key.  Send the RSA private key separately.  Never ever store the private key on the device.

Any asymmetric public key/private key encryption method will do, it doesn't have to be RSA.

Comment: unfortunately it is not possible to use RSA or any public/private key in this case, the only possibility is using symmetric key and store it in a device (unmanned device) in a secure way. (we should consider a hacker can access the device and we should try to find a software solution for storing key) this key is needed for communication among unmanned devices.

Comment: In that case use a simple XOR encryption to mask the key on the device.  Authorised users will have the appropriate unmasking key to allow them to get at the real key.  You will need to change the masking key regularly for security, that is why RSA is a better solution.

Comment: @saghar the asymmetric encryption is not used for the security of the communication but for the security of the symmetric key used for the communication. @ rossum how to avoid that any hacker can intercept the private key when it's sent to the device?